# How to remove blank from dropdown and required validation working in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a dropdown, I'm binding it with `owners`, but its giving extra blank option. I want to remove the blank option from it. I'm able to do but when I add these changes my required validator does show error.

```
<md-input-container>
        <select name="owner" ng-model="form.owner" ng-options="owner.UserName for owner in owners"
                class="input-div" style="height:30px" ng-change="ownerTypeChange()" required ng-disabled="update && view">
          <option style="display:none" value=undefined>Select an owner</option>
        </select>
        <div ng-messages="DataAccessRoleForm.owner.$error">
          <div ng-message="required">required</div>
        </div>
      </md-input-container>
```

If I remove the below line, then required validator works but dropdown has the blank option.

```
<option style="display:none" value=undefined>Select an owner</option>
```

Comment: on your controller make your model equal to the first element of your options array `form.owner = owners[0]` to pre select your first option

Comment: but I don't want to select anything by default.

Comment: then you will have an empty option  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @FabioAntunes  cute smiley :P

Answer (score 1):

Check if your select has been touched before displaying the required message.

```
<div ng-if="form.owner.$touched" ng-message="required">required</div>
```

You can also set the default option to be selected but not selectable once they open the drop down.

```
<option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select an owner</option>
```

Comment: Getting this error.
Controller 'ngMessages', required by directive 'ngMessage', can't be found!